# Importing Numpy fails after building from source against amd blis

Tags: python, numpy, blas, cblas

I'm trying to build a local version of Numpy from source against BLIS (for BLAS and CBLAS) and against OpenBLAS for LAPACK.

I started with building BLIS locally for zen3 with CBLAS enabled, like so:

```
./configure --enable-threading=openmp --enable-cblas --prefix=$HOME/blis zen3
```

then ran the tests (which all passed) and ran `make install`. I made sure all relevant files are in the $HOME/blis library (see attached screenshot).

I also built openBLAS locally, no special configs there.

Afterwards, I modified numpy's `site.cfg` to configure openBLAS and blis folders' accordingly:

```
[blis]
libraries = blis
library_dirs = /home/or/blis/lib/
include_dirs = /home/or/blis/include/blis
runtime_library_dirs = /home/or/blis/lib/

[openblas]
libraries = openblas
library_dirs = /opt/OpenBLAS/lib
include_dirs = /opt/OpenBLAS/include
runtime_library_dirs = /opt/OpenBLAS/lib
```

I continued by building and installing numpy with:

```
NPY_BLAS_ORDER=blis NPY_LAPACK_ORDER=openblas NPY_CBLAS_LIBS= python ./numpy/setup.py build -j 32
```

Note that `NPY_CBLAS_LIBS` is empty as numpy's build docs say to do so if CBLAS is included in the BLIS library, which it is.

Then,  importing numpy resulting in:
`Original error was: /home/or/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.24.0.dev0+998.g6a5086c9b-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm`

I'm clueless at this point as I couldn't find anything online about this specific case.

Installing numpy from pip (which comes built with openblas) can be imported successfully.

Update 1:
While reading `make install` logs, I found out that it couldn't find my BLIS library files at the location, even though the files are in the specified path. I also tried to recompile and install BLIS in various paths and reconfigure numpy before compiling it, but got the same result.

When I downloaded a pre-compiled version of BLIS from AMD's website, numpy seems to get it, but this isn't the recommended way to go because I'm missing optimizations for Zen3.

Comment: Wild shot: does adding `/opt/OpenBLAS/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` help?

Comment: @user3840170 do you mean BLIS? Because using OpenBLAS was never an issue, it just works.

Comment: What's the output to ldd /home/or/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.24.0.dev0+998.g6a5086c9b-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so ? It sounds like it's trying to dynamically load some dependencies and it failing to find them